# Relational functions not working in laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

Order by is working for this one...

```
$posts   = PostClass::where('thread_id',1)->orderBy('id','desc')->paginate(20);
```

but order by is not working for this one.

```
$thread = ThreadClass::find(1);
$posts   = $thread->posts()->orderBy('id','desc')->paginate(20);
```

Laravel Version : 5.5

Comment: getting in `error` ?

Comment: Please show your `posts()` function

Answer (score 2):

To allow orderBy to happen on the related posts you can access the dynamic property as a relationship method.

```
$posts = $thread->posts()->orderBy('posts.id','desc')->paginate(20);
```